# UML: How to implement a template interface?

Tags: uml

Suppose I have an aggregate type and I want to use it in conjunction with a template iterator. The following C# code gives an exact example of my model:

```
public interface Iterable<T>
{
    Iterator<T> iterator();
}

public abstract class Letter
{
}

public abstract class Alphabet : Iterable<Letter>
{
    public abstract Iterator<Letter> iterator();
}

public abstract class Iterator<T>
{
    public abstract void first();
    public abstract void next();
    public abstract bool done();
    public abstract T get();
}
```

But I have a little problem when capturing this in UML. The problem is that I'm not sure how to combine two relationships between *Alphabet* and *Iterable*: Template Binding and Realisation. I ended up in depicting them separetly but for that I had to introduce two intermediate entities for that and this looks a bit clumsy.

[image]

You see these new interface *AlphabetIterable* (binds *Iterable* with *Letter*) and class *AlphabetIterator* (binds *Iterator* with *Letter*).

Is there a way to make an equivalent UML model without these two intermediates?

Comment: Thanks, @Snowman.  I considered erasing the watermark, but my OCD gene wasn't activated this morning.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I thought about that too, but a quick pass did not work very well due to jpeg compression adding fuzz around the edges of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picture below shows how Sparx Systems Enterprise Architect's code reverse engineering visualizes the relationship between `Alphabet` and `Iterable` when fed with your code snippet.

[image]

I've added the `«bind»` stereotype manually to make it compatible with

> [www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/Beta2](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/Beta2/PDF/) → **7.3.4** Common Structure → Templates → Notation
>
> ...
>
> A `TemplateBinding` is shown as a dashed arrow with the tail on the bound element and the arrowhead on the template and the keyword `«bind»`. The binding information may be displayed as a comma-separated list of template parameter substitutions:
>
> <template-param-substitution> ::= <template-param-name> ‘->’ <actual-template-parameter>
>
> ...

See also:

- [uml-diagrams.org: Template Binding](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/template.html#template-binding)

Comment: That was as easy as falling off a log. :-) I'm only starting learning UML and using Enterprise Architect and haven't tried this feature yet. Thank you, @xmojmr!